# Angular CLI - How to pick up .spec.ts files outside of the src folder?

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have an Angular CLI project with a `NgModule` located outside of the `/src` folder (eventually this NgModule will be packaged as a npm module but for now I'm just leaving it outside of `/src`).

I'm trying to write unit tests for this NgModule but `ng test` doesn't seem to pick up `.spec.ts` files outside of the `/src` folder.

I have tried altering the path in `/src/test.ts`:

```js
// Original
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

// Does not work
const context = require.context('../', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

// Does not work
const context = require.context('/absolute/path/to/ngmodule', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

But I get an error: `Module build failed: Error: /absolute/path/to/file.spec.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.`

I have also tried adding the path to my NgModule in the `include` property of `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
"include": [
  "../my-ng-module/**/*.spec.ts",  // Added this
  "**/*.spec.ts",
  "**/*.d.ts"
]
```

But no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

> In tsconfig.spec.json

```
 "include": [
    "../*.spec.ts", // your spec file location parent of src or ../yourpath/
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

> In test.ts
>
> if you pick parent dir it picks the other specs as well, hence when
>   picking the parent dir of src then give your component name or specify
>   the exact path of your spec

```
 const context1 = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);//
 const context = require.context('../', true, /app\.component\.spec\.ts$/);//
 context.keys().map(context);
 context1.keys().map(context1);
```

When you are in the parent folder of src the same context is picking up the files which are in node_modules,hence we need to mention the spec.ts name.

spec.ts files which are in src will run like before
[image]

app spec is in parent of src and game spec in is in src folder

> If you want to specify only the root directory and from there you want
>   to pick all the spec files then we give a different naming convention
>   which differs from the spec files in node_modules. Say which are out
>   of src as yourapp.componentout.spec.ts and which are inside
>   insideapp.componentin.spec.ts and you can give one path instead of two
>   directories

```
const context = require.context('../', true, /out\.spec\.ts$|in\.spec\.ts$/);//
context.keys().map(context);
```

or the other way follow the naming convention for the files which are outside of src only and put

```
 const context1 = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);//
 const context = require.context('../', true, /out\.spec\.ts$/);//
 context.keys().map(context);
 context1.keys().map(context1);
```

if you don't want to change the spec file names , then give the path of your module location instead of its parent where you can skip the node_modules part.

Basically, We can change the below according to our needs

```
  require.context(directory, useSubdirectories = false, regExp = /^\.\//)
```

Hope this helps !!!

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context

Comment: Great answer! I would never have thought of additional context's in `tests.ts`, I havn't seen documentation around this anywhere. Thanks a lot for posting

Comment: :) Thank you! i am glad that it helped you :)

Comment: What noticed is that you cannot use variables in `require.context`, as it seems that webpack parses it rather than interprete it?!

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting, this is what I was searching for exactly

Answer (score 0):

The following command will help

```
ng test --include='src/app/modulefolder/**/*.spec.ts'
```