# Testing angular components outside of main project folder: module not found raw-loader

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

So I want to run ng test and include tests in a folder next to the projectfolder.

```
mainproject/
|-- src/
|   |-- app/
|   |   |-- home/
|   |   |   |-- home.component.spec.ts  
|   |   |-- app-main.component.spec.ts
|   |-- test.ts
|   |-- tsconfig.spec.json
|-- node_modules/
|-- angular.json
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
components/
|-- common/
    |-- control-bar/
        |-- control-bar.component.ts
        |-- control-bar.component.spec.ts
```

When I run ng test without including the other tests in the components folder it works as intended, but when I try to include the other components ng test fails with the following error.

```
ERROR in ../components/common/control-bar/control-bar.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader' in 'absolutepath\repos\components\common\control-bar'
resolve 'raw-loader' in 'absolutepath\repos\components\common\control-bar'
  Parsed request is a module
  No description file found
  resolve as module
    absolutepath\repos\components\common\control-bar\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    absolutepath\repos\components\common\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    absolutepath\repos\components\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    absolutepath\repos\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    absolutepath\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    C:\Users\user\Desktop\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    C:\Users\user\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    looking for modules in absolutepath\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules
      using description file: absolutepath\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        using description file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder absolutepath\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/raw-loader)
          no extension
            absolutepath\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\raw-loader doesn't exist
          .js
            absolutepath\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\raw-loader.js doesn't exist
          .json
            absolutepath\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\raw-loader.json doesn't exist
          as directory
            absolutepath\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\raw-loader doesn't exist
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\components\common\control-bar\package.json]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\components\common\control-bar\node_modules]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\components\common\node_modules]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\components\node_modules]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\node_modules]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\node_modules]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\node_modules]
[C:\Users\user\node_modules]
[C:\Users\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\raw-loader]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\raw-loader.js]
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\repos\mainproject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\raw-loader.json]
 @ ../components/common/control-bar/control-bar.component.ts 13:34-85
 @ ../components/common/control-bar/control-bar.component.spec.ts
 @ ./src/test.ts
```

So raw-loader seems to be missing or it can't find it. To be clear there is only 1 node_modules in this setup and it's inside the mainproject folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364840/angular-cli-how-to-pick-up-spec-ts-files-outside-of-the-src-folder

See if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue and I've abandoned the search for a proper solution. For now I'm making it work by making sure the dependencies of the library are installed separately (so having a second `node_modules` folder in the library).

Since there is nothing to be found on the subject and the [official angular documentation for creating libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) mentions that it is required for libraries to be built:

```
Build the library. You cannot use a library before it is built.
```

I'm assuming dynamically linking to unbuilt libraries without its own `node_modules` is simply unsupported (even though it works fine as long as there are no component classes imported in the library).